# Unable to wrap text in UILabel, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I've seen several SO questions without much help.

I am creating a UILabel with edge insets using a custom class in a view controller like this `var message  =  InsetLabel()`. In `viewDidLoad` I am customising the label, to wrap the text, but it doesn't seem to work. Where am I going wrong ?

I dont get the full text as you can see in the below image:

[image]

```
class InsetLabel: UILabel {
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)))
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
var messageHeading  =   UILabel()
var message         =   InsetLabel()
var messageText  =  "Your profile is currently going through the approval process, You will be notified as soon as it has been appproved."

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        messageHeading.text             =   "APPROVAL STATUS"
        messageHeading.textColor        =   Colors.darkGrey
        messageHeading.textAlignment    =   .left

        message.text                =   messageText
        message.textColor           =   Colors.darkGrey
        message.textAlignment       =   .left
        message.lineBreakMode       =   .byWordWrapping
        message.numberOfLines       =   10
        message.backgroundColor     =   Colors.white
        message.sizeToFit()
        view.addSubview(messageHeading)
        view.addSubview(message)

        messageHeading.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        message.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let views = ["messageHeading"   :   messageHeading,
                     "message"          :   message
        ]

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-20-[messageHeading]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[messageHeading]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[messageHeading]-10-[message]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[message]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
}
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the number of lines?

Answer (score 0):

Change your custom label class

```
class InsetLabel: UILabel {
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect)
       // super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)))
    }
}
```

Then add constraints like this:

```
  let msgHeadVerticalConst =  NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-20-[messageHeading(>=20)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
let msgHeadHorizontalConst = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[messageHeading]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

let msgVerticalConst =          NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[messageHeading]-10-[message(>=20)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

let msgHorizontalConst = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[message]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate(msgHeadVerticalConst + msgHeadHorizontalConst + msgVerticalConst + msgHorizontalConst)
```

Comment: Could you try by adding height constraint as well.

Comment: It works if I add height constraint but I would like it to be set based on text content as this would help me to avoid the iterative process to get the correct height.